# Threading implications of common caching idiom

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching

A common caching idiom is to check for the presence of an item in the cache, retrieve if present or create if not.

Does this not create a condition whereby if a context switch from `Thread 1` to `Thread 2` occurs at the commented location, the value added to the cache may be immediately overwritten when the context switch back to `Thread 1` occurs? The downside being that `calculateFooBar()` has now been invoked twice to calculate the same cached item. Is this just an accepted "minor" consequence of this simple caching implementation. Is a critical section not typically used because that would add overhead to all `GetOrCreate` methods?

Edit: _cache is a reference to a shared data cache (e.g. the ASP.NET data cache).

```
//not real C#
class FooBarDictionary
{
    ...

    FooBar GetOrCreate(string key)
    {
        FooBar fooBar;

        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out fooBar))
        {
            fooBar = calculateFooBar(); //context switch occurs here
            fooBars.Add(key, fooBar);
        }

        return fooBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: `_cache` is safe for gets/sets, but does not make `FooBar` safe. As Darin said, if you're .NET 4.0, you have the concurrent collections to help you, otherwise the _easiest_ approach is to serialize updating this `FooBar` instance.

Comment: Okay, thanks to Darin and yourself for your input. I suppose the origin of the question was that I don't recall seeing locks in use in idiomatic examples of "GetOrCreate". This may simply be my poor memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program works correctly even if you had two instances of that object and only the resource allocation time & memory is your concern I wouldn't bother adding locks. In the long run thread syncronization can be more expensive.

ConcurrentDictionary<> would be a good choice for such "nolock" container, as others mentioned already.

Comment: Aha - this is something I suspected! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything will depend on what this `_cache` variable is: it's type and scope. If it is a static variable and not thread safe such as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you need to synchronize access to it using a `lock`. In .NET 4.0 you have the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) type which achieves similar things in a thread safe manner. Your code is fine but without a `lock` there is no guarantee that the calculation wouldn't occur twice for the same key in a very short lapse of time.

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.robvolk.com/2009/06/aspnet-data-caching-helper-extension.html) for a nice implementation of this pattern. Also if you are using .NET 4.0, you could use the new [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) assembly.

Comment: `_cache` is a reference to a shared data cache such as the ASP.NET data cache, which although thread-safe would not avoid the duplicate calculation issue I identified above?

Comment: @Ben Aston, to avoid this *double calculation issue* you could use a *lock*.

Comment: "This being said, if this is supposed to be code written for caching, well, you shouldn't be writing such code but use some of the built-in caching mechanisms in .NET such as the System.Runtime.Caching assembly." Are you saying the "cache check followed by a calculation and store if not present" is not a recognised caching idiom? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Ben Aston, it is indeed a very well recognized caching idiom. But in order to ensure that you don't perform the calculation twice for the same key you might need to lock. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We use in several scenarios some custom caching... the new `Concurrent`* - Collections in .NET 4 are extremely well suited for such impelementations...

With `foobars` being a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, FooBar>` you could do something like:

```
return foobars.GetOrAdd (key, (k) => calculateFooBar() );
```

This code would replace the whole body of you sample method `GetOrCreate` .

For more insight see http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx